# How can I use intent to a class from another packet?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

In my app in android a have many classes and I want to order them in differents packets. The problems is that if I have in the packet "com.List" the class List.class and in the packet "com.List.Fruit" the class "Fruit.class" and I try an intent from List.class to Fruit.class I get "Force Close". What should I do? Where is my mistake? I mention that in AndroidManifest I put both of activitys. Any idea is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Follow the java naming conventions: package names should be lower case only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either full package name Like List.class.ClassName or include that package in class.

Comment: I still get "Force close" even if I use Intent j1 = new Intent(List.this, com.List.Fruit.Fruit.class); or I import com.List.Fruit.Fruit;

Comment: I think your package name is com.List.Fruit. So you should use this only not "com.List.Fruit.Fruit"

Comment: 05-02 09:16:25.771: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(445): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.List/com.List.Fruit.Fruit}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 05-02 09:16:25.771: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
05-02 09:16:25.771: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)

Comment: In AndroidManifest I have to declare Fruit.class to package "com.List.Fruit"? In my AndroidManifest I have only the package "com.List"

Comment: But the problem is that I don't know how to declare the package.

Comment: You can use directly package name in activity like as you have declared activity as ".Fruit", use "com.List.Fruit.Fruit"

Answer (score 0):

follow the package name as explained here.
if ur package is : **com.app.** where "com.app" is common
so while you register your class in manifest file and if you have followed the pattern like

Then do same for the rest of the classes and if u want like :

then do for the rest of the new calsses